# Realm reset schema version

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I'm currently in the process of writing an app that uses Realm as a database. As I'm still writing it my models have invariably changed from what I initially designed. Unfortunately every time this happens I need to update a migration block.

Is there anyway to 'reset' my Realm so that until it's actual in 'production' I don't need to worry about Migration blocks at all? It's particularly a pain with some unit tests, I do actually delete all the tables when the tests run, but I'm assuming there must be a best practice to handle this

Specifically I am working in an iOS/Swift app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is very useful solution, just type:

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
```

Comment: Is there something similar to .NET and C#?

Comment: this is pretty much c# ...

RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(realm_db_name);
                config.ShouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded = true;

                var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);

Comment: Is it a good idea to use this in tests? It solves the problem of migrations. If not please suggest how to handle migrations in tests?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on real database in tests but on mock conforming to database protocol instead